# Is it better to take two ID columns as one for indexing another for referencing for few tables in my situation?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

There are few tables in the current databases in which I am working, with more than two ID columns one with auto increment, for indexing another unique ID column in which IDs are generated by the programmer and stored which is for indexing. 
          I never seen such scenario before. the answer why they took like that is, When they merge the data which is generated at one db server can be easily merged with another database without conflict. because there are few relationships existed between them.

The problem if you use single auto incremented ID,

- group of records will be inserted into primary tables with the same
  id referred into its foreign tables. If this data merged into another
  database in which some data already exists, they may conflict with
  the auto generated IDs in that DB.
- e.g. TBL_1 is the main table which is referred in 10 other tables, so
  the id geenrated in TBL_1 must be retained while dumping into another
  DB. May be there are some records already with same ID, exists. then
  conflict arises.
- or else if you leave increment process to the new DB the those 10
  referred table will lost integrity with this table.

Is this is the right way, to use.(It is an existed system, not created by me).

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Is the primary key defined as PK(auto_increment,GUID) or is only the auto_increment part defined as primary key?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any benefit in the auto-increment columns. The way I understand your question, all the referencing is accomplished using the explicitely generated IDs. I believe that explcitely generating IDs at the application level for this reason is perfectly valid, but I'd make these generated IDs the only ones, to keep the system simpler and easier to understand. And it will prevent future modifications to accidentially use the wrong ID, i.e. the one which won't survive a merging into another database.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic:

- Either you'll need to use a globally unique identifiers (such as GUID or some sort of globally visible "ID server") that have no chance of conflicting between different databases.
- Or you'll need to translate your IDs from one "namespace" to another, recursively including all the foreign keys.

BTW, while it is true GUID will throw the rows all over the place in [InnoDB clustered table](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/), auto-increment will actually have the similar effect (just more dependent on timing of INSERTs). And don't forget that the secondary index in clustered table is expensive (it needs to contain a copy of the PK and may cause a double-lookup).

Unless you have a specific reason for an auto-incremented ID (such as keeping child FKs slim), just use the application-generated ID as the PK. And if you make it globally unique, that'll avoid any need for ID translation and dramatically simplify the merging process...

Comment: It's not true. You have the 3rd option, it's a compound key made from auto_increment and integer column that defines the location of the server/mysql (an arbitrary integer). Even if you merged the data all together without replication, you'd have integrity intact and everything would work.